# How do I show a default image file when some particular image file is not found?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I request images for user's profile photos from amazon s3 bucket,  but if the image file is not found for some user I want to redirect to an alternate default image file for profile photo. If this redirect is possible with amazon s3 then how do I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

There are different solutions based on how (which technology you use) you render your html.
For example, this is a plain HTML solution:

```
<body>
  <object data="https://assets.mozilla.org/Brands-Logos/Firefox/logo-only/invalid_image.png" type="image/png">
    <img src="https://assets.mozilla.org/Brands-Logos/Firefox/logo-only/firefox_logo-only_RGB.png" />
  </object>
</body>
```

If the `invalid_image.png` does not exist, `firefox_logo-only_RGB.png` will be shown.

**[EDIT]**

In order to handle default images via s3 buckets, this is what can be done:

1. Upload the default image (eg. *default_image.png*) to the bucket (eg. *my_image_bucket*).
2. Update the bucket properties. `Bucket Properties > Static Website Hosting > Error Document` ==> set *default_image.png* in the textbox.

Now, the default_image.png will show up whenever a file is not found.

Eg.

```
<body>
   <!-- This will result in default_image.png being rendered -->
   <img src="http://my_image_bucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/invalid_image.png" />
   <!-- The actual image will be rendered -->
   <img src="http://my_image_bucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/valid.png" />
</body>
```

**PS**: Do make sure that you are using the s3 Endpoint as what shows up in the `Static Website Hosting` section.

Comment: isn't there some way to do a redirect from s3, I am requesting image directly from amazon s3 url so my server wont play any role here..

Comment: Thanks  T J for the answer! Is the S3 method,  a recommended standard way to accomplish this behavior or this is just a hack to make it work ?

Comment: Because although the fallback image is shown while requested image is unavailable but the response header shows `STATUS CODE: 403 Forbidden`. This would happen for a large no of requests as large no of users wont have profile photo uploaded. Isn't this a concern ?

Comment: This is a custom 403 document, not a 200/301 in place of 403/404. Hence, it will always show 403 as the response code. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html#configure-bucket-as-website-routing-rule-syntax)'s more on routing rules. Are you using something like _userId.png_ for user images? Why don't you have a _default_image.png_ for users who haven't uploaded their images yet and a flag (field) marking the actual _imageId_ (perhaps a null in case they don't have an image)?

Comment: yeah exactly I am using `userId.jpg` for user's profile photo & to simply things at my end I avoided storing flag field to identify whether or not file exists. However I just got another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28524654/530153

Comment: cool. You might want to create a trail of user uploads. You will lose the trail if the user uploads a new image. You could go for s3 versionized buckets or a different name per upload. Anyway, that is needed only if you want to keep a trail.